# How do you filter updates to specific fields from ChangeStream in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am setting up a ChangeStream to notify me when a document has changed in a collection so that I can upsert the "LastModified" element for that document to the time of the event.  Since this update will cause a new event to occur on the ChangeStream, I need to filter out these updates to prevent an infinite loop (updating the LastModified element because the LastModified element was just updated...).

I have the following code that is working when I specify the exact field:

```
ChangeStreamOptions options = new ChangeStreamOptions();
options.ResumeAfter = resumeToken;

string filter = "{ $and: [ { operationType: { $in: ['replace','insert','update'] } }, { 'updateDescription.updatedFields.LastModified': { $exists: false } } ] }";
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>().Match(filter);

var cursor = collection.Watch(pipeline, options, cancelToken);
```

However, instead of hard-coding the "updateDescription.updatedFields.LastModified", I would like to provide a list of element names that I don't want to exist in the updatedFields document.

I attempted:

```
string filter = "{ $and: [ { operationType: { $in: ['replace','insert','update'] } }, { 'updateDescription.updatedFields': { $nin: [ 'LastModified' ] } } ] }";
```

but this didn't work as expected (I still got the update events for the LastModified change.

I originally was using the Filter Builder:

```
FilterDefinitionBuilder<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>> filterBuilder = Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter;
FilterDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>> filter = filterBuilder.In("operationType", new string[] { "replace", "insert", "update" });  //Only include the change if it was one of these types.  Available types are: insert, update, replace, delete, invalidate
filter &= filterBuilder.Nin("updateDescription.updatedFields", ChangedFieldsToIgnore); //If this is an update, only include it if the field(s) updated contains 1+ fields not in the ChangedFieldsToIgnore list
```

where ChangedFieldsToIgnore is a List containing the field names that I do not want to get events for.

Can anyone help with the syntax that I need to use? or do I need to create a loop around my ChangedFieldsToIgnore list and create a new entry in the filter for each item to "$exists: false"?  (this doesn't seem very efficient).

**EDIT:**

I attempted the following code based on the answer by @wan-bachtiar, but I'm getting an exception on my enumerator.MoveNext() call:

```
var match1 = new BsonDocument { { "$match", new BsonDocument { { "operationType", new BsonDocument { { "$in", new BsonArray(new string[] { "replace", "insert", "update" }) } } } } } };
var match2 = new BsonDocument { { "$addFields", new BsonDocument { { "tmpfields", new BsonDocument { { "$objectToArray", "$updateDescription.updatedFields" } } } } } };
var match3 = new BsonDocument { { "$match", new BsonDocument { { "tmpfields.k", new BsonDocument { { "$nin", new BsonArray(updatedFieldsToIgnore) } } } } } };
var pipeline = new[] { match1, match2, match3 };

var cursor = collection.Watch<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>(pipeline, options, Profile.CancellationToken);
enumerator = cursor.ToEnumerable().GetEnumerator();

enumerator.MoveNext();
ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument> doc = enumerator.Current;
```

The exception is: `"{"Invalid field name: \"tmpfields\"."}"`

I suspect the problem might be that I'm getting "replace" and "insert" events which do not contain the updateDescription field, so the $addFields/$objectToArray are failing.  I'm too new to figure out the syntax, but I think I need to use a filter that does:

```
{ $match: { "operationType": { $in: ["replace", "insert"] } } }
OR
{ $eq: { "operationTYpe": "update" }} AND { $addFields....}
```

Also, it appears that the C# driver does not include a Builder that helps with the $addFields and $objectToArray operations.  I was only able to use the `new BsonDocument {...}` method to build the pipeline variable.

Comment: Are you not wanting to see the whole update event that contains `updateDescription.updatedFields.UnwantedField` ? Because `updatedFields` may contain more than one fields, for example, it may contains `LastModified` and another field that was updated in the same operation.

Comment: My application is the only one that should be updating the LastModified field, so in my case that would be ok.  However, if you have a proposal for a filter that would only exclude updates that contain a subset of the list of fields to ignore, I'd love to see it.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with the $redact aggregation operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ChangedFieldsToIgnore is a List containing the field names that I do not want to get events for.

If you would like to filter based on multiple keys (whether `updatedFields` contains certain fields), it's easier if you convert the keys to values first.

You can convert the document contained within `updatedFields` into values by utilising aggregation operator [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/). For example:

```
pipeline = [{"$addFields": {
             "tmpfields":{
               "$objectToArray":"$updateDescription.updatedFields"}
            }}, 
            {"$match":{"tmpfields.k":{
                       "$nin":["LastModified", "AnotherUnwantedField"]}}}
];
```

The above aggregation pipeline adds a temporary field called `tmpfields`. This new field will pivot the content of `updateDescription.updatedFields` turning `{name:value}` into `[{k:name, v:value}]`. Once we have those keys as values, we can utilise `$nin` as an array of filter.

**UPDATED**

The reason you're getting an exception of `tmpfields` being invalid, is because the result is casted into [ChangeStreamDocument](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/v2.5.x/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/ChangeStreamDocument.cs#L25) model which does not have a recognizable field called `tmpfields`.

In the case, when it's different operations that does not have field `updateDescription.updatedFields`, the value of `tmpfields` would just be `null`.

Below is an example of MongoDB ChangeStream .Net/C# using [MongoDB .Net driver v2.5](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/), along with an aggregation pipeline that modifies the output change stream.

This example is not type safe, and would return `BsonDocument` :

```
var database = client.GetDatabase("database");            
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");

var options = new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };

// Aggregation Pipeline
var addFields = new BsonDocument { 
                    { "$addFields", new BsonDocument { 
                       { "tmpfields", new BsonDocument { 
                         { "$objectToArray", 
                           "$updateDescription.updatedFields" } 
                       } } 
                 } } };
var match = new BsonDocument { 
                { "$match", new BsonDocument { 
                  { "tmpfields.k", new BsonDocument { 
                    { "$nin", new BsonArray{"LastModified", "Unwanted"} } 
            } } } } };

var pipeline = new[] { addFields, match };

// ChangeStreams
var cursor = collection.Watch<BsonDocument>(pipeline, options);

foreach (var change in cursor.ToEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine(change.ToJson());
}
```

Comment: I think this is getting close to where I need, but I'm running into a new exception about tmpfields being an invalid field name.. I suspect it is when the document is not an opType "update", but is "insert" or "replace".  I've edited the OP with my attempt from your answer.

Comment: @JerrenSaunders , I've updated my answer with an example code. This is not due to different operation type, but just the model cast. i.e. `ChangeStreamDocument`.

Comment: Thanks.  This gets me close enough to where I need to be.  I'll still need to convert this BsonDocument over to a ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument> which I've managed to do, but I'm sure there is a better way that what I've put together now... I'll ask that in a new question though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the piece of code below as I was having the same issues you were having. No need to mess around with BsonObjects ...

```
//The operationType can be one of the following: insert, update, replace, delete, invalidate
//ignore the field lastrun as we would end in an endles loop
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<ATask>>()
    .Match("{ operationType: { $in: [ 'replace', 'update' ] } }")
    .Match(@"{ ""updateDescription.updatedFields.LastRun"" : { $exists: false } }")
    .Match(@"{ ""updateDescription.updatedFields.IsRunning"" : { $exists: false } }");

var options = new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };
var changeStream = Collection.Watch(pipeline, options);    

while (changeStream.MoveNext())
{
    var next = changeStream.Current;
    foreach (var obj in next)
        yield return obj.FullDocument;
}
```