# How can I use BsonClassMap to change the way a MongoDB C# Driver class is deserialized?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Due to the filter I'm applying to my changestream (discussed at SO: [How do you filter updates to specific fields from ChangeStream in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49633124/2136313)), I am getting a BsonDocument back instead of a ChangeStreamDocument object.  The only thing different about this BsonDocument from a ChangeStreamDocument is that it contains an extra element called "tmpfields".

In my scenario, I still need the ResumeToken and other elements in the document, so I'd like to convert this BsonDocument to a ChangeStreamDocument object.  My first attempt was to use `BsonSerializer.Deserialize<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>( doc)` where doc was the BsonDocument I got back.  However, since it had the extra tmpfields element, this isn't allowed.

I attempted to register a BsonClassMap since the ChangeStreamDocument class is part of the C# driver and I couldn't add the [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] attribute to the class, but I wasn't successful:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
});
```

The `AutoMap()` didn't work though and I got an exception about "no matching creator found".  I tried to `cm.MapCreator(...)`, but wasn't succesffuly there either.  I took the `AutoMap()` call out (only leaving the SetIgnoreExtraElements line) and got errors about it not being able to match the properties (_id, etc).  So I tried lines like `cm.MapProperty(c => c.DocumentKey).SetElementName("documentKey")` for each of the properties, but they were never set when I used the `Deserialize()` method - they were left as null.

For now, I've reverted to using `doc["field"].AsXYZ` method to get the values that I need from the BsonDocument, but I'd like to learn a better way to do this.

Is using the RegisterClassMap the correct approach?  If so, what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I couldn't add the [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] attribute to the class

If you just want to ignore the extra field. You could just add an extra aggregation pipeline `$project` to remove the field.

For example

```
var options = new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };
var addFields = new BsonDocument { { "$addFields", new BsonDocument { { "tmpfields", new BsonDocument { { "$objectToArray", "$updateDescription.updatedFields" } } } } } };
var match = new BsonDocument { { "$match", new BsonDocument { { "tmpfields.k", new BsonDocument { { "$nin", new BsonArray{"a", "b"} } } } } } };

// Remove the unwanted field. 
var project = new BsonDocument { {"$project", new BsonDocument { {"tmpfields", 0 } } } };
var pipeline = new[] { addFields, match, project };

var cursor = collection.Watch<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>(pipeline, options);

var enumerator = cursor.ToEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
     ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument> doc = enumerator.Current;
     Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentKey); 

 }
```

Comment: I had done the projection in my earlier attempts, but I thought that the generic type parameter for my Watch method needed to match the type for the pipeline (BsonDocument).  Good to know that I do as you described.  It would still be helpful to know how to convert from a BsonDocument to an different type without having to manually match the properties, or without having to convert to JSON then re-parse.